# RecursionError while iterating over list

Tags: python

I have a list of geodesic points by the format: `[lat, long, elevation, index, land/sea binary classifier]` in a grid formation with regular spacing throughout the dataset.  I'm trying to find all neighbouring points that are land (elv > 0) to the current point in the list.

I keep getting this error:  `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the repr of a list` and although I understand the sort of thing that could be causing this, I have no idea how this applies to this situation as I'm not explicitly using recursion.  How am I able to remedy this error?  How can I understand the problem better as well?

(topLat, bottomLat, westLong, eastLong are the lats and longs for the first and last point in the grid/map to identify points at the edge of the map)

```
def buildNeighbours(point, dataset):
    neighbours = []
    ix = int(point[3])

    if point[0] != topLat and point[0] != bottomLat and point[1] != westLong and point[1] != eastLong:
        nw = dataset[ix - (rowLength + 1)]
        n = dataset[ix - rowLength]
        ne = dataset[ix - (rowLength - 1)]
        e = dataset[ix + 1]
        se = dataset[ix + (rowLength + 1)]
        s = dataset[ix + rowLength]
        sw = dataset[ix + (rowLength - 1)]
        w = dataset[ix - 1]
        neighbours = [nw, n, ne, e, se, s, sw, w]
        point.append(neighbours)

    else:
        point = []

    return point


for point in dataList:
    point = buildNeighbours(point, dataList)

print(dataList[2000])
```

Comment: You could get this if a list item is in fact a reference to the original list. `repr` would keep circling back to the top of the nested lists.  Your code is really long so I haven't tried to figure out where the problem is. Do you have a shorter version that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Whenever it has to excute the if statement, the error occurs

Comment: The error is very much self-explanatory - you've managed to implement infinite loop somehow.
Short sample (3-7 entries) of your data list plus the way you run this script may help the community to assist you.
None seems to be possible to evaluate from your current code though

Comment: I think that you get an error in one of the `if` calculations, python tries to raise an error, but hits a recursion error when generating the error message. Put a `print(repr(point))` at the top of the function and it will likely hit. Then you can deal with that.

Comment: What is `point`? It seems like a list of ints or floats but then you append a list to it. Is that intentional?

Comment: What is `rowLength`?

Comment: Is the `RecursionError` happening immediately, or after a long wait?  I could produce exponentially-huge strings for a 3x3 grid, where the fan-out is limited, but I gave up waiting for the `repr` of a 4x4.  I never produced a `RecursionError` though.

Comment: Any more information on this?

Answer (score 1):

To stringify a point (really a `list`), `print` must first get the string representation of every element.  The last element of each point is a `list` of neighboring points, each of which is a `list` that contains yet another `list` of neighboring points... one of which is the original point.  And so it continues...

`list`'s `__repr__` attempts to limit recursive cases, eventually giving up and returning `'...'`.  Assuming it uses the same defaults as [`reprlib.Repr` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/reprlib.html#repr-objects), the `maxlevel` (max recursion depth) is 6.  With 8 neighbors each, that could mean thousands of visits to a relatively small number of unique points.

I was able to print a 3×3 grid, where the fan-out is limited because most of the points only have 3 or 5 neighbors (corners and sides).  My simplified `point` lists, which didn't contain altitude or land/sea elements, required about 700kiB to represent the whole grid... about 40KiB for the upper-left corner alone.  On a 4×4 grid, a single point ballooned up to about 16MiB.

That said, I'm guessing what your inputs look like, and I probably haven't reproduced what you're really doing.  More importantly, I did *not* get a `RecursionError` like you did, perhaps because I gave up waiting for it.

With those caveats in mind, I suggest:

- In each point's `neighbors` list, store the *indices* of the neighbors.  Look them up later whenever you need them.  (This is the simplest solution I could come up with.)  Write a couple helper functions that calculate the northwest or south or whatever neighbor of a given index, since you'll be doing that a lot.
- Alternatively, consider creating a `neighbors` dictionary, mapping each point's index to a list of indices.  You'd have to keep that dictionary alongside `dataList` at all times, but it would let you remove the list of neighbors from all of your points.
- If you really have to store the neighbors themselves, create a `Point` class with custom `__str__` and `__repr__` methods that don't try to print the neighbors.  As a bonus, a class would let you refer to fields with names like `lat`, `lng`, and `index` instead of mysterious subscripts like `[1]` and `[3]`.